# Mutliple HeatMapWithTime instances in a Folium map

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-visualization, heatmap, folium

I'm trying to plot a double Heatmaptime on the same map.

```
m = folium.Map(location=[-3.72,-38.54],zoom_start=11,max_zoom=16,min_zoom=7,tiles='OpenStreetMap')
plugins.HeatMapWithTime(
    prova_1,
    radius=8,
    index=time_index_1,
    #min_opacity=0.8,
    #max_opacity=1.2, 
    #use_local_extrema=True,
    #gradient= gradient_map_1,
    #auto_play=True,
    overlay=True,
    control=True,
    show=True,
).add_to(m)
# Display the map
plugins.HeatMapWithTime(prova,
    radius=8,
    index=time_index,
    overlay=False,
).add_to(m)
```

However, it always displays the first map but not the second. Separately both work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this problem is still on the table.

A (very) rough workaround is to remove `overlay=False,` from your second `HeatMapWithTime` and add:

```py
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
```

at the end of your code. Then untoggling and retoggling the layer controls should do the job:

[image]

Of course, this is NOT a clean solution. But still something temporarily useful.